# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'solc' " Using py-solc and solidity

Tags: solidity, solc, python

**I installed py-solc and solidity:**

solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9.Darwin.appleclang

**and ran this code in python (with a contract source example):**

```
from solc import compile_source, compile_files, link_code

    source = """
    pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
    contract Example {
        string s="Hello World!";
        function set_s(string new_s) {
            s = new_s;
        }
        function get_s() returns (string) {
            return s;
        }
    }"""

compiled = compile_source(source)
```

**and the compile_source() function returned this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    compile_source("pragma solidity ^0.4.0;\n contract Foo {}", output_values=["bin", 'abi'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/solc/main.py", line 106, in compile_source
    stdoutdata, stderrdata, command, proc = solc_wrapper(**compiler_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/solc/utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/solc/wrapper.py", line 155, in solc_wrapper
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'solc'
```

**how is it possible to fix this issue and compile using py-solc?**

Answer (score 9):

The problem is solc is not installed on your pc.
get it installed through

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solc
```

or you can go [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this. For me it happened as a result of switching the python environment. Anyway, this can be solved by installing `py-solc`, or better `solc-select`.

```
pip3 install solc-select
```

Slyther repo [issue](https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/464).

Answer (score 0):

There is also an *experimental* feature to [ask py-solc to install `solc` for you](https://github.com/ethereum/py-solc#installing-the-solc-binary):

> Any of the following versions of `solc` can be installed using `py-solc` on the
>   listed platforms.
>
> - `v0.4.1` (linux)
> - `v0.4.2` (linux)
> - `v0.4.6` (linux)
> - `v0.4.7` (linux)
> - `v0.4.8` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.9` (linux)
> - `v0.4.11` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.12` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.13` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.14` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.15` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.16` (linux/osx)
> - `v0.4.17` (linux/osx)
>
> Installation can be done via the command line:
>
> ```
> $ python -m solc.install v0.4.17
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am on LinuxMint using Python3.6, you can run:

```
$ sudo pip install py-solc
```